# Display error message when login button is clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display an error message if a user tries to login and has an invalid email or password.  I want to display this error under the password input container.  And I want to use the same style of the 'errors' section using Angular. That can be seen here

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<md-content id="login" layout="column" layout-align="center center" class="inputdemoErrors">
<div flex="25"></div>
  <p class="m0">project</p>
    <form id="loginForm">
      <md-input-container>
        <label for="username">Email Address</label>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container class="email-field">
        <input name="username" id="username" type="email" class="validate" ng-model="username" enter-key="submitLogin()" autocomplete="off" required>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container class="password-field">
        <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="validate" ng-model="password" enter-key="submitLogin()" autocomplete="off" required>
        <div ng-show="invalid" ng-messages="loginForm.username.$error" role="alert">
          <div ng-message="required">Invalid Email or Password</div>
        </div>
      </md-input-container>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" style="width: 100%; margin: 0; background-color: #29B6F6;" ng-click="submitLogin()">Login</a>
  </form>
</md-content>
```

JS

```
(function () {
 'use strict';

  angular
   .module('login')
   .controller('LoginCtrl', LoginCtrl);

  function LoginCtrl($scope, $location, SecService, RecService, Service) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.ctrlName = 'LoginCtrl';

  $scope.submitLogin = function() {
  $scope.invalid = $scope.loginForm.$invalid;
  if($scope.invalid) {
    return;
  }
  else
    $scope.dataLoading = true;
    var creds = {
      username: $scope.username,
      password: $scope.password
    };
    SecService.login(creds).then(function (response) {
      if (response.success) {
        RecService.connect();
        SecService.setCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
        Service.loadCurrentUser();
        $location.path('/main');
      } else {
        $scope.dataLoading = false;
      }
    });
  };
 }
}());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some things...

on submitlogin, you need to test and expose if your form is invalid:

```
$scope.submitLogin = function() {
    $scope.invalid = $scope.loginForm.$invalid;
    if($scope.invalid) return;
    ...
```

and then, at html, you prevent to show the message early with ng-show:

```
<div ng-show="invalid" ng-messages="loginForm.username.$error" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">Invalid Email or Password</div>
</div>
```

you need too to correct the form tag, putting the name attribute, required for angular ngModel:

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm">
```

Comment: I changed the code to reflect your changes, but I am still not getting the results I am looking for.  And 'loginForm' in the JS file says 'unresolved variable loginForm'.  Not sure why.

Comment: Also I am very new to JS/HTML so I could use all the help I can get with this issue.

Comment: Excuse-me, I didn't verify your code correctly. Your <form> must be a name="loginForm" to be recognized for angular. It also affects the ng-messages test. Correct this and try again.

Comment: If this answer is correct, you can mark as correct to help other people too. :-)